# How to merge two aggregate functions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to merge two aggregate functions in SQL Server.

Code:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), SYSDATETIME(), 3), '/', '') AS [DDMMYY],
    (count(Sno)+1) AS count 
FROM tbl_demographic_reg
```

Output:

```
DDMMYY   count

060114  1
```

I need the above output to be `06011400001` - how to get it? Thanks

Comment: Concat & Convert http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just concatenate them together, adding necessary zeroes in between:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), SYSDATETIME(), 3), '/', '') + 
    right('0000' + cast((count(Sno)+1) as varchar(5)), 5)
FROM tbl_demographic_reg
```

Comment: its showing error "Incorrect syntax near 'cast', expected 'AS'." what to do...?

Comment: Sorry, misplaced brackets. Please try now.

Comment: thanks...if sno return 10 then o/p is 000010 but i need it 00010..dynamiclly it should reduce zero's how to do...?

Comment: Is it? When you do `SELECT right('0000' + cast(10 as varchar(5)), 5)` it returns `00010` correctly...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), SYSDATETIME(), 3), '/', '') +
    RIGHT('0000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,count(Sno)),6)
FROM tbl_demographic_reg
```